# How to transfer value from SVG map

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg, svg.js

I am collected a SVG map from https://pixelmap.amcharts.com/., I want when I click a city on the map this city value transfer on my data base. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you really using [SVG.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js) and not [amCharts's JavaScript Maps](https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js)? If you are using [SVG.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js) and can publish your map somewhere, then I can create an example for you.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Mullany for your comment. I have already done.